# How to disable security for an Action in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2, forms-authentication

My requirement is that only the login page and the Register page should be accessible from anonymous users. 
I have created a new ASP.NET MVC project using the default template in VS2008.

After that I have enabled security adding this section to the web config:

```
    <authorization>
        <deny users="?" />
    </authorization>
```

Now the Register Action is not accessible anymore because of the security enabled. How I can do to disable security only for that Action?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will want to use the `Authorize` attribute on your controller actions to restrict access at the Controller or Action level:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute.aspx

Answer (score 6):

I would recommend you using the [`[Authorize]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute.aspx) attribute to control which actions/controllers require authentication instead of using `web.config`. This way your authorization rules are less vulnerable to errors if you decide to modify your routes.

Answer (score 1):

In context of ASP.NET MVC 4: you can enable authorization with the [Authorize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute.aspx) attribute on your controller classes, then disable for specific actions with the [AllowAnonymous](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.allowanonymousattribute%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) attribute.