# How to make ASP.NET MVC View Insecure via location tag in Web.Config

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

I have the following authorization settings in my web.config:

```
 <authorization>
      <deny users="?" />
 </authorization>
```

This deny's all anonymous access to the application accept the login page. In addition to this I am using authorization within each controller action via a custom authorize attribute.

I have one additional action that I would like to expose publicly in addition to the login page. This particular action does not have the authorization attribute on it. I have tried to make this view (resetPassword view) public by using the location tag in the web.config file like so:

```
 <location path="Account/ResetPassword" allowOverride="false">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
```

In the path attribute above I have tried both the view as well as the action path, but it doesnt allow public access to the action.

I have even tried to put this view in a separate folder within the shared folder and put a separate web.config file to make that folder public like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <authorization>
      <allow users="*" />
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

None of the above configuration allow me to make this particular action (view) public. Can anyone suggest any other solutions, or what I may be doing wrong in this case?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please see the comments for the below post for the actual answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can remove the authorization tag from the web config and just use the authorize attribute.
The action without the Authorize atttribute set will be public.

I had the same problem some time ago. Please have a look to [this question and its answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653333/how-to-disable-security-for-an-action-in-asp-net-mvc)

If you want to do it using the web config then use code like this

```
<!-- Allow access to _assets directory -->
<location path="_assets">
    <system.web>
       <authorization>
           <allow users="?"/>
       </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
```

In your sample you are using "*" but you should use "?" ;)

Comment: I understand that but I am under the assumption that this way there is a second level of security implemented by the web.config over the entire contents of the web application. I wanted to keep that as well. Is there a way I can do that?

Comment: @Nosh: I have edited my answer as per your requirement. Try with this.

Comment: Thank you for your help, unfortunately changing the character doesnt resolve the issue for me.

Comment: @Nosh: sorry it did not help. I use the code that I have posted to make the assets (js, css, images) available also if the user is not logged in and it works. But in my case that's a real path. In your case the Controller/Action is not a path on the file system so I think you should remove the "second level of security" and just rely on the Authorize attribute that is what you really need. Good luck!

Comment: I agree, I think the location attribute is more suited for a web forms environment where there are actual physical pages in the application. Otherwise the ASP.NET MVC team needs to look into this and implement the location attribute for MVC as well. But for the time the Authorize attribute will have to do and will provide the only level of security.